# Teamcity, how to define which VCS had triggered the build

Tags: version-control, build, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

In my Teamcity build configuration I have three VCS configured:
[image: VCS configuration]

If any of those would have a check-in - the trigger would fire and my build would be running.

What I need to know - which from those repositories had fired the trigger.
What I can know is the type of the trigger event: `echo %teamcity.build.triggeredBy%` (in case if the build was triggered automatically it would say "GIT") , however, I don't' see any option to know which VCS had triggered the build.

Any thoughts how this could be achieved?